# Flex container overflow to the left of the viewport and I'm unable to scroll to it

Tags: html, css

So I created a couple of flex containers with similar styling, for each container, the children become double of the children of the previous container and this makes it flow out of the viewport left and right. The problem is I can scroll to the right of the container both not to the left overflowed view, I want to be able to scroll both ways. Please see below a sample of my code for further clarification

```css
.zoom-out {
  position: relative;
  height: 91vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 4rem 20px 7rem;
}

.zoom-out__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 50px;
}

.zoom-out__container:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.zoom-out__child {
  min-width: 16rem;
  max-width: 16rem;
  font-family: Work Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 140%;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-out">
  <div class="zoom-out__container">
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="1">Genesis block</div>
  </div>
  <div class="zoom-out__container">
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="11">First Gen, Firs Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="12">First Gen, Second Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="13">First Gen, Third Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="zoom-out__container">
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="111">Second Gen, First Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="112">Second Gen, Second Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="113">Second Gen, Third Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="121">Second Gen, Fourth Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="122">Second Gen, Fifth Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="123">Second Gen, Sixth Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="131">Second Gen, Seventh Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="132">Second Gen, Eight Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="133">Second Gen, Nineght Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="134">Second Gen, Tenth Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="135">Second Gen, Eleventh Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="136">Second Gen, Twelveth Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="zoom-out__container">
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="1211">Third Gen, First Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="1212">Third Gen, Second Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="1213">Third Gen, Third Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="1214">Third Gen, Fourth Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="1215">Third Gen, Fifth Child</div>
    <div class="zoom-out__child" id="1216">Third Gen, Sixth Child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to put the container .zoom-out in position:absolute.

Comment: Thank you, this came in handy. 